# Hide header of a section

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2012. The programming language is C#.

In the report, there are some sections. In one of this, there are the headers of the data will be displayed in other section. I need to hide this headers if the data is an empty string. How can I do this?

Note: I don't want to hide entire section where there are the headers, because there are more information in this section. I need to hide ONLY the headers.

Thanks!

Edit: more details.

The design of the report is [this](http://prntscr.com/38ff7l)  (it is in spanish).

If the "Codigo" field is empty string (in "Section3(Detalles)"), the header "Codigo" (in bold, in GroupHeaderSection1) will be hided. The same for the other fields.

Comment: `Report Header` or `Page Header` ??

Comment: That would depend on the specifics of the data and structure of your report. Could you add more detail to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right Click on the section (Header either Report Header or Page Header) and select "Section Expert.."
2. You will see Suppress (No- Drill-Down) check box under "common" tab and next to it a button . Click on it
3. There write a condition using the report field (which you gonna use to determine whether to hide/un hide section)

   i.e  `if(Length({reportfield})=0)then true`

Comment: This hides all the section, but I need to hide only the headers :S

Comment: @JoséPersichini: You need to do this on specific header!!